# boost ssl half close socket is possible?

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I have ssl-server and ssl-client. it almost same with Boost ssl example.

now,

server open(listen) then client join and send data to server.

when sending data is done

close socket from client with `socket_.lowest_layer().close();`

I want change this to somethings half-close : send close, read open

and client should be send `boost::asio::error::eof` before half-close.

Then server catch `boost::asio::error::eof` and close socket from server.

Is there any more good matter? and boost have half-close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP half-close (shutdown for output) cannot be used with SSL. SSL sends a `close_notify`, so as to enable truncation attacks to be detected, and this logically closes the SSL connection in both directions. If you just shutdown the underlying TCP socket yourself, SSL will consider that a truncation attack and make the SSL connection unusable.

I don't understand why you want to change to what you described. SSL already does essentially that itself with the `close_notify`.

Comment: thank you for comment. is there any other way to close socket from server. i think close from client can be danger...// my server only can catch eof when client closed..and i need other way

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Just close it, at the SSL layer. You don't have to wait for the client to close first, although if he is still sending he will get an error of course.

Comment: when many clients are connect to server. and clients will just close when they send finish. at this time i worried about server keep the socket or session until timeout or else. is it useless worried?

Comment: You should use a read timeout at the server, long enough to allow whatever period of client inactivity you deem reasonable, and if it happens just close the socket.

Comment: It should be noted that TLS 1.3 now allows a half-close. However it's not the answer to this question.