# No CloseRead() / CloseWrite() implementation for tls.Conn

Tags: go, ssl, open-source

I am currently trying to switch a Go server from using a `net.TCPConn` to using a `tls.Conn` for its API calls. The problem I am running into is that my server relies on `net.TCPConn`'s ability to close the read and write connection independently (via `net.TCPConn.CloseRead()` and `net.TCPConn.CloseWrite()`), a feature which is not implemented at the `net.Conn` level or in `tls.Conn` implementation.*

* I know that `tls.Conn` does have an implementation of `CloseWrite()`, but under the hood this method only calls `SetWriteDeadline()` and doesn't close the file descriptor, which is the functionality that I need.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a specific design reason for not having an implementation for `CloseRead()` and `CloseWrite()` in `net.Conn`? It looks like the implementations of `net.Conn` that have these methods define them almost identically.
2. Why isn't there an implementation of these methods in `tls.Conn` which closes the file descriptors?

Thank you in advance for your response!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204982/boost-ssl-half-close-socket-is-possible

Comment: In Go 1.18, you can `c.NetConn().(*net.TCPConn).CloseWrite()`. I don't know if that makes sense within the context of TLS.

Comment: I did try casting the `tls.Conn` to a `net.TCPConn` in order to avoid changing any function headers, but unfortunately `tls.Conn` is composed of a `tls.Conn` and has added fields so the cast fails.

Answer (score 1):

> ... my server relies on net.TCPConn's ability to close the read and write connection independently ...

Relying on this is usually done to signal to the peer that no more data will be sent while still being able to receive data. This ability is specific to TCP, where one side can send a FIN to signal end of transmission while still receiving data.

Since it is not a generic feature of network connections but specific to TCP it makes no sense to provide an interface for this in the generic net.conn. Similar TLS also does not have the concept of a read-only connectivity after a one-side shutdown - see  [boost ssl half close socket is possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204982/boost-ssl-half-close-socket-is-possible) for details.

Comment: That makes sense. My problem lies in the fact that my server wants to close reads and allow writes to finish flushing before closing the write half, whereas `close_notify` as mentioned in the post you linked only applies to the write half.